# NVProf for NCCL program

Tags: cuda, nvidia

When I want to use NVProf for NCCL problem with --metrics all, The profiling results always return me like

```
==2781== NVPROF is profiling process 2781, command: ./nccl_example 2 16
==2781== Profiling application: ./nccl_example 2 16
==2781== Profiling result:
```

No events/metrics were profiled.
My simple nccl program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "nccl.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ncclComm_t comms[4];


  // managing 4 devices
  int nDev = 3;
  int size = 32*1024*1024;
  int devs[4] = {0, 1, 2};

  //allocating and initializing device buffers
  float** sendbuff = (float**)malloc(nDev * sizeof(float*));
  float** recvbuff = (float**)malloc(nDev * sizeof(float*));
  cudaStream_t* s = (cudaStream_t*)malloc(sizeof(cudaStream_t)*nDev);


  for (int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i) {
    CUDACHECK(cudaSetDevice(i));
    CUDACHECK(cudaMalloc(sendbuff + i, size * sizeof(float)));
    CUDACHECK(cudaMalloc(recvbuff + i, size * sizeof(float)));
    CUDACHECK(cudaMemset(sendbuff[i], 1, size * sizeof(float)));
    CUDACHECK(cudaMemset(recvbuff[i], 0, size * sizeof(float)));
    CUDACHECK(cudaStreamCreate(s+i));
  }


  //initializing NCCL
  NCCLCHECK(ncclCommInitAll(comms, nDev, devs));

   //calling NCCL communication API. Group API is required when using
   //multiple devices per thread
  NCCLCHECK(ncclGroupStart());
  for (int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i)
    NCCLCHECK(ncclAllReduce((const void*)sendbuff[i], (void*)recvbuff[i], 
                                size, ncclFloat, ncclSum, comms[i], s[i]));
  NCCLCHECK(ncclGroupEnd());


  //synchronizing on CUDA streams to wait for completion of NCCL operation
  for (int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i) {
    CUDACHECK(cudaSetDevice(i));
    CUDACHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(s[i]));
  }


  //free device buffers
  for (int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i) {
    CUDACHECK(cudaSetDevice(i));
    CUDACHECK(cudaFree(sendbuff[i]));
    CUDACHECK(cudaFree(recvbuff[i]));
  }


  //finalizing NCCL
  for(int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i)
      ncclCommDestroy(comms[i]);

  printf("Success \n");
  return 0;
}
```

Because I need to know the detailed metrics of NCCL APIs such that I can get more insights of its performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is expected.

[events, metrics,](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#event-summary-mode) that are gathered by default pertain to CUDA device code activity.  To see something that might be instructive, try profiling with `--print-gpu-trace` switch  (and remove `--metrics all`).

The [documented](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference)  "metrics" don't apply to the operations (data copying) that NCCL is doing.  They apply to CUDA kernels (i.e. CUDA device code activity).

`nvprof` does seem to have metrics that can be collected for NVLink activity.  To see these, on a system that is applicable (e.g. has NVLink), run a command such as:

```
nvprof --query-metrics
```

or

```
nvprof --query-metrics |grep -i nvlink
```

Comment: One more follow-up question, How could I get the information such as the NVLink throughput when I was suing NCCL? Thanks

Comment: `nvidia-smi` can give you NVLink statistics, see [here](https://www.exxactcorp.com/blog/HPC/exploring-nvidia-nvlink-nvidia-smi-commands)  You can also get NVLink information from [Nsight Systems](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/latest-nsight-developer-tools-releases-nsight-systems-2021-1-nsight-compute-2021-2-nsight-visual-studio-code-edition?ncid=so-face-102436#cid=gtcs21_so-face_en-us) and in [the visual profiler](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvlink)

Comment: if I want to know the NVLink through information for a NCCL program , should I use `ncu` command instead of `nvprof`,  because in the detailed metrics of `nvprof`, I found one entry that is useful `NVLink Transmit Throughput `

Comment: Sorry, this is not the question you asked.  It's not appropriate on SO to have an extended discussion in the comments on something not related to your question.  If you have a new question, I suggest asking a new question.